# Get data from flutter web index file into any dart file in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart-js-interop

I want to get data from Firebase notifications and show it on my Flutter web. But I am unable to do so. I am trying to use `js: ^0.6.7` but am unable to get data.
I want to get into my Stateful class at runtime.

Comment: Are you using https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging_web ?

Comment: No, I am using firebase_messaging.